# How do you update class and id tags in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Is there a way to change or add class/id tags to items in Drupal?  For instance, I want to change a certain set of images but the only class listed on all images is "img-responsive."

I'm very new to Drupal and trying to teach myself everything in a very limited amount of time. So if you answer, please provide clear directions/provide screenshots that a newbie could understand! I really appreciate any guidance or direction to my possible next steps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an absolutely too broad question. You should invest the time to teach yourself about Drupal's theming system and about its preprocessing hooks first.

Start with [Working With Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates) which will teach you among other things how to create a custom template and change markup or attributes (class, id etc.) according your needs.

Next checkout [Preprocessing and modifying attributes in a .theme file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file). Which assumes you have created a custom theme or sub-theme. There are some hooks you can use to programmatically change classes of certain elements.

---

`img-responsive` tells me that you are using some theme that uses some CSS framework. Hopefully you already created your own sub-theme. Then you can add something like the following to your modules `.theme` file.

To add a class directly to the `<img>` tag you can identify it by its image style:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_image().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$variables) {

  // Check the image style.
  if ($variables['style_name'] == 'img_fluid') {

    // Add class.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'img-fluid';
  }
}
```

If you want to add a class to a image field (the wrapping container), you can target a field by its name:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {

  // Check for your image field.
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_MYIMAGE') {

    // Add class.
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'img-fluid';
  }
}
```

---

Source: [How to add a class to the image tag in field.html.twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263721/15055)